# org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize in Hibernate code

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

I am getting the error in the second line here.

```
qlString = "select r FROM Hotspot r "
              + " left outer join fetch r.G1 g1 "
                 + " left outer join fetch r.G2 g2 "
                 + " left outer join fetch r.G3 g3 "
                 + " left outer join fetch r.G4 g4 "
                 + " left outer join fetch r.G5 g5 "
                 +" join r.A a "
                  +" left outer join fetch r.FR rm "
            + "where a.id= :aId";           
query = session.createQuery(qlString);
query.setParameter("aId",lid);
hpts =(List<Hotspot>)query.list();
```

This is my Hibernate Entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="HOTSPOT")
@NamedQuery(name="Hotspot.findAll", query="SELECT f FROM Hotspot f")
public class Hotspot implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="HOTSPOT_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="HOTSPOT_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="HOTSPOT_ID_GENERATOR")
private long id;
```

This is the partial stack trace

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:53)
```

Hibernate version

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Edit: Updated the question with Hibernate version and query.

Comment: Please show what query do you run? What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Updated the post with details.

Answer (score 0):

Your not showing the whole mapping, but it looks like you are using an unsupported Java class type for an attribute which Hibernate tries to deserialize through the Java deserialization mechanism, but it fails because the data apparently is not a valid Java serialization stream.

I guess you forgot to put `@Entity` or `@Embeddable` on some class or some class is not scanned or you forgot to register it in the persistence.xml.